# "accessorize" method - Ruby, Rack or Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

I've seen the following idiom, and wonder what does `accessorize` mean and where does it come from - Ruby, Rack or Sinatra?

```
use Rack::Flash, accessorize: [:error, :success]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`accessorize` not method, from listing i see this is [Rack::Flash](https://github.com/nakajima/rack-flash) key options. And deep in the source i see this:

```
# Generate accessor methods for the given entry key if :accessorize is true.
def def_accessor(key)
  raise ArgumentError.new('Invalid entry type: %s' % key) if respond_to?(key)

    class << self; self end.class_eval do
      define_method(key) { |*args| val = args.first; val ? (self[key]=val) : self[key] }
      define_method("#{key}=") { |val| self[key] = val }
      define_method("#{key}!") { |val| cache[key] = val }
    end
  end
end
```

In documentation

> Or you can pass the `:accessorize` option to declare your flash types.
>   Each of these will have accessors defined on the flash object

Look [source code](https://github.com/nakajima/rack-flash/blob/master/lib/rack/flash.rb).